# Call a class that extends another class from main method

Tags: java, inheritance, bar-chart, overriding

So I have a class that draw a bar chart. I got the code from here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartSample extends Application {
final static String austria = "Austria";
final static String brazil = "Brazil";
final static String france = "France";
final static String italy = "Italy";
final static String usa = "USA";

@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final BarChart<String,Number> bc = 
        new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
    xAxis.setLabel("Country");       
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("2003");       
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 10000));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 35407.15));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 12000));      

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("2004");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 57401.85));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 41941.19));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 45263.37));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 117320.16));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 14845.27));  

    XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    series3.setName("2005");
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 45000.65));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 44835.76));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(france, 18722.18));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(italy, 17557.31));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(usa, 92633.68));  

    Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
    bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

But the problem is I want to call this BarChartSample class from my main method in another class.
For example, I have a class called BookRecommender and has a main method. I want to be able to set the parameters such as title, xlabel, ylabel and also values of this BarChartSample class. But I cannot run the start method of the BarChartSample class from my Recommender class.

Comment: Can you modify the BarChartSample class or must it stay as it currently is?

Comment: You can modify as you think is better. I just want the functionality of a bar chart to draw a chart for me.

Comment: OK, it sounds like you want someone else to do the work for you. That's not really what stack overflow is for. Try and make the class, based of this example, yourself and if you then have issues with the said class, feel free to ask another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a JavaFX application, so you wouldn't directly call this class from another class. You need to encapsulate the functionality of this class in a class and then call it from a JavaFX application.

E.g. you could subclass Scene to create a specific BarChartScene and then pass the data you require in the constructor or a method setData([data you wish to pass]). Or you could create a BarChartSceneFactory class that would return a Scene object.

E.g.
SceneFactory.java

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

public abstract class SceneFactory {
    private static final String AUSTRIA = "Austria";
    private static final String BRAZIL = "Brazil";
    private static final String FRANCE = "France";
    private static final String ITALY = "Italy";
    private static final String USA = "USA";

    public static Scene getBarChartScene() {
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc = new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");     
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");       
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(AUSTRIA, 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(BRAZIL, 20148.82));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(FRANCE, 10000));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(ITALY, 35407.15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(USA, 12000));      

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(AUSTRIA, 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(BRAZIL, 41941.19));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(FRANCE, 45263.37));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(ITALY, 117320.16));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(USA, 14845.27));  

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(AUSTRIA, 45000.65));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(BRAZIL, 44835.76));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(FRANCE, 18722.18));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(ITALY, 17557.31));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(USA, 92633.68));  

        Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        return scene;
    }
}
```

MainApp.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = SceneFactory.getBarChartScene();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

You can then simple call SceneFactory.getBarChartScene() in your main sample application to get a Scene object and set it on your Stage.

If you wish your own custom data to be displayed, then pass it to the getScene method as a parameter e.g. `Map<Integer, Map<String, Double>> chartData` where the first integer holds the year, which maps to a mapping of country name to values.

Or you could subclass Scene and do it that way too e.g.

```
public class BarChartScene extends Scene {
    public BarChartScene([pass some data in here]) {
        // Build your scene based on the data passed in the constructor.
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way in Java that I can have a class that draw Bar chart and  use this class within my other classes? I think any other languages migh have this ability. I mean drawing a bar chart is a very typical thing to do in scientific programming and we might use this class a lot in our program

Comment: Yes, you CAN do it, but you need to take the functionality OUT of this JavaFX application first, then call it from another.

Comment: It does, you just need to refactor the example code into such a class.

Comment: I am not a Java programmer and my main language is R. In R , drawing a bar chart is very easy. But since I have a source code of a project in Java, I have to code in Java. So if you can please tell me what you mean by taking the functionality out of JavaFX.

Comment: Not the functionality out of JavaFX, but creating your own class that does the above code for you. The libraries are already there under javafx.scene.chart.* You just need to work through them and build the class yourself for your own needs

Comment: Sorry, you need to learn Java first. If you don't know what I mean by extracting code and encapsulating it elsewhere in a separate module, then you won't understand any answer given to you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Your sample already does what you're asking here. What we're trying to explain to you is that if you wish to call the functionality you have at present from a different application, then you need to encapsulate the code into a separate module that can be called from your application. That's your answer. You are going to have to learn Java in order to facilitate that answer. I've already given you an example Factory class above that will return you a Scene. All you need to do is to create a JavaFX application subclass that gets its Scene from this factory and set it on the Stage.

Comment: If you wish to view different data, then you'll need to pass the data in a method or a constructor.

Comment: I really don't know what stage is or what scene is. Ok. In R, draw a bar chart is as simple as this: 
    counts <- table(mtcars$gear)barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", 
   xlab="Number of Gears")
That is why I have a hard time here

Comment: Then you need to learn Java. And specifically JavaFX. This isn't a site to teach you how to code. It's a site to fix problems you are having with your coding. Hopefully these will help you.

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part6/

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm

Comment: @ManoDestra
So I did what you said and I built that Scene Factory class and I called it from my main method. 
    public abstract class SocialOptimalRecommender extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args, Stage stage) throws IOException, TasteException {

        stage.setScene(SceneFactory.getBarChartScene());
        stage.show();

    }
But I get InstantiationException.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105925/discussion-between-himanucc-and-manodestra).

Comment: I've edited the answer with two complete classes now, the SceneFactory class and the MainApp application class. I've tested it and it works. If you wish to pass data to the getBarChartScene() method, you can. And you can amend this method to return a Scene based on the data you pass to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Does your main class extend Application as well?  If so, I would modify the code you have so that it doesn't extend Application.  You can add methods to modify whatever data you need.  You could even just copy and paste the code you need into your application.

Comment: If my main extends Application, I should override the start method of the Application which to be honest I don't think it's right to do.

Comment: The problem is I want to use this Chart class within my main method after I calculated some values and then I pass those values to the Chart class to draw a bar chart. I don't want the chart class to be automatically called when I run my program

Comment: Then do as I've told you above and it will work just fine.